# Codeplex: cannot log in with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, codeplex

I'm trying to login to Codeplex's TFS server using visual studio 2015.
I've done this in the past, and it has always worked.

Now however, I changed my PC and on my new visual studio installation I cannot login with the login info they provide.

Basically, whenever I try to log-in, visual studio keeps showing the login popup again and again, without any error message.

The credentials are correct, I double and triple checked them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below ways to figure out the access issue:

- Clear the user and password info stored in **Windows Credential**
  (Control Panel-Credential Manager)
- Disable the firewall and antivirus software
- [Clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)
- Log out your account in the old machine and try again
- Make sure that you have selected Visual Studio Team Foundation Server for source control. To do this, go into the Visual Studio options menu and select **Visual Studio TFS** as the Current source control plug-in. Then, select **Tools  Options- Source Control - Plug-in Selection.**
- If you are still having trouble, try going through the “**Forgot Password**” link to reset your password. *(Note: you need to use Forgot Password, and not the normal Change Password option).* Try connecting again.

Comment: Did point 1 and point 5, one of them fixed the problem. Thanks